# microsoft lumia 535 shows airplane mode and restarting

Tags: nokia-lumia-535

My new microsoft lumia 535 restarts automatically after approximately one hour and before restarting, it shows aeroplane mode (but my airplane mode is allready off.) what is the solutions for this????

Comment: Can you specify the OS version??